# My react app is rendering a blank page but I do not know what the error is

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have tried everything. I have wasted the whole day trying to figure it out so i would like your help on it.On my localhost i can only see a blank webpage and i do not know what the problem is. I am relatively new to this and i will appreciate any help i can  get. I am trying to create an amazon clone and so far everything has been going great except for this one thing. I dont know whether the problem is in the app.js or the reducers but everything was working great before i added more code to both files so i highly suspect that the problem is from one of the files or both of them.

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import Header from './Header';
import Home from "./Home"
import Checkout from './Checkout';
import Login from './Login';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth } from './firebase';

function App() {
  const[{}, dispatch] = useStateValue()


  useEffect(()=>{
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser)=>{
      if(authUser){
        
        dispatch({
          type:"SET_USER",
          user:authUser
        })
      }else{
        
        dispatch({
         type:"SET_USER",
          user:null
        })
      }
    });

    return ()=>{
      unsubscribe()
    }
  },[dispatch])

    return(
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/'   element={<><Header/> <Home/></>}  />
          <Route path ="/checkout" element={<> <Header/> <Checkout/></>}/>
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
      </Router>
    )
}

export default App;
```

here is the reducer

```
export const initialState ={
    basket:[],
    user:null
}

export const getBasketTotal = (basket)=>
    basket?.reduce((amount,item)=>item.price +amount,0);


const reducer = (state,action)=>{
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_USER":
            return{
                ...state,
                user:action.user
            }
        case "Add_to_basket":
            return{
                ...state,
                basket:[...state.basket,action.item]
            }         
            
            case "Remove_from_basket":
                let newBasket = [...state.basket];

                const index  = state.basket.findIndex((basketItem)=>basketItem.id===action.id)

                if (index>=0){
                    newBasket.splice(index,1);
                }else{
                    console.warn(
                        
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-template-curly-in-string
                        'Cant remove product (id: ${action.id} ) as it is no longer in basket '
                    )
                }



            return{...state,basket:newBasket}
            
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


export default reducer
```

Comment: Does an error show in the Developer Tools (right-click, hit "Inspect")?

Comment: Yes the error is (Uncaught Typerror:firebase_compat_app__webpack_imported_moudle_o__default.auth is not a function